# Trigger referring to another subelement table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

In SQL Server there two tables: `Invoices` (InvoiceId, Number, Date, Customer, TotalValue) and `InvoicesElements` (InvoiceId, Good, Qty, Value).

Each transaction inserts one row into `Invoices` and one/many rows into `InvoicesElements`.

I need to set a trigger on the `Invoices` table that will raise an error and rollback transaction when `Good` in the `InvoicesElements` table is 'Bike' and Customer is 'ABC'.

Any help much appreciated.

Przemek

Comment: Any reason you want a trigger and not a check constraint?

Comment: No, constraint would do as well. But how ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE
        InvoicesElements
ADD CONSTRAINT
        CHK_GOOD
CHECK   (good <> 'Bike' OR good IS NULL)
```

Update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
        TR_InvoicesElements_AIU
ON      InvoicesElements
AFTER   INSERT, UPDATE
AS
        IF EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    INSERTED ie
                JOIN    Invoices inv
                ON      inv.id = ie.invoiceId
                WHERE   ie.good = 'bike'
                        AND inv.customer = 'ABC'
                )
                THROW 50000, 'Not sure why but you cannot sell bikes to ABC', 0
GO

CREATE TRIGGER
        TR_Invoices_AIU
ON      Invoices
AFTER   INSERT, UPDATE
AS
        IF EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    InvoiceElements ie
                JOIN    INSERTED inv
                ON      inv.id = ie.invoiceId
                WHERE   ie.good = 'bike'
                        AND inv.customer = 'ABC'
                )
                THROW 50000, 'Not sure why but you cannot sell bikes to ABC', 0
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was something - conditions must be set on both tables: Good <> 'Bike' but also Customer<>'ABC'. So ...